# Output data from all columns in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with the name `params.csv`. I opened up `ipython qtconsole` and created a pandas `dataframe` using:

```
import pandas
paramdata = pandas.read_csv('params.csv', names=paramnames)
```

where, `paramnames` is a python list of string objects. Example of `paramnames` (the length of actual list is 22):

```
paramnames = ["id",
"fc",
"mc",
"markup",
"asplevel",
"aspreview",
"reviewpd"]
```

At the ipython prompt if I type `paramdata` and press enter then I do not get the dataframe with columns and values as shown in examples on [Pandas website](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/indexing.html#additional-column-access). Instead, I get information about the dataframe. I get:

```
In[35]: paramdata
Out[35]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 59 entries, 0 to 58
Data columns:
id                    59  non-null values
fc                    59  non-null values
mc                    59  non-null values
markup                59  non-null values
asplevel              59  non-null values
aspreview             59  non-null values
reviewpd              59  non-null values
```

If I type `paramdata['mc']` then I do get the values as expected for the `mc` column. I have two questions:

(1) In the examples on the pandas website (see, for example, the output of `df` here: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/indexing.html#additional-column-access) typing the name of the dataframe gives the actual data. Why am I getting information about the dataframe as shown above instead of the actual data? Do I need to set some output options somewhere?

(2) How do I output all columns in the dataframe to the screen without having to type their names, i.e., without having to type something like `paramdata[['id','fc','mc']]`.

I am using pandas version 0.8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is too much data to be displayed on the screen, therefore a summary is displayed instead.

If you want to output the data anyway (it won't probably fit on a screen and does not look very well):

```
print paramdata.values
```

converts the dataframe to its numpy-array matrix representation.

```
paramdata.columns
```

stores the respective column names and

```
paramdata.index
```

stores the respective index (row names).

Comment: -1 as I think `set_printoptions` should be mentioned. `paramdata.values` isn't a good solution, because probably `numpy` will not show all too (depending on the size) and the index information is lost.

Answer (score 325):

Use:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', 7)
```

This will force Pandas to display the 7 columns you have. Or more generally:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

which will force it to display any number of columns.

Explanation: the default for `max_columns` is `0`, which tells Pandas to display the table only if all the columns can be squeezed into the width of your console.

Alternatively, you can change the console width (in chars) from the default of 80 using e.g:

```
pandas.set_option('display.width', 200)
```

Comment: set_option seems to be new, perhaps from version 0.13?  For earlier versions try e.g. pd.set_printoptions(max_columns=7)   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-widen-output-display

Answer (score 31):

I know this is an old question, but I have just had a similar problem and I think what I did would work for you too.

I used the to_csv() method and wrote to stdout:

```
import sys

paramdata.to_csv(sys.stdout)
```

This should dump the whole dataframe whether it's nicely-printable or not, and you can use the to_csv parameters to configure column separators, whether the index is printed, etc.

Edit: It is now possible to use `None` as the target for `.to_csv()` with similar effect, which is arguably a lot nicer:

```
paramdata.to_csv(None)
```

Comment: `.to_csv(None)` is cleaver :-)

Answer (score 22):

In `ipython`, I use this to print a part of the dataframe that works quite well (prints the first 100 rows):

```
print paramdata.head(100).to_string()
```

Answer (score 9):

you can also use `DataFrame.head(x)` / `.tail(x)` to display the first / last x rows of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 8):

I'm coming to python from R, and R's `head()` function wraps lines in a really convenient way for looking at data:

```
> head(cbind(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars))
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  mpg cyl
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 21.0   6
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 18.7   8
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 18.1   6
                  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  mpg cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4          160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 21.0   6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag      160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 21.0   6  160 110
Datsun 710         108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 22.8   4  108  93
Hornet 4 Drive     258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 21.4   6  258 110
Hornet Sportabout  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 18.7   8  360 175
Valiant            225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 18.1   6  225 105
                  drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I developed the following little python function to mimic this functionality:

```
def rhead(x, nrow = 6, ncol = 4):
    pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
    seq = np.arange(0, len(x.columns), ncol)
    for i in seq:
        print(x.loc[range(0, nrow), x.columns[range(i, min(i+ncol, len(x.columns)))]])
    pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', True)
```

(it depends on pandas and numpy, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sequence slicing syntax i.e

```
paramdata[:5] # first five records
paramdata[-5:] # last five records
paramdata[:] # all records
```

sometimes the dataframe might not fit in the screen buffer in which case you are probably better off either printing a small subset or exporting it to something else, plot or (csv again)