# How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, printing, column-width

Is there a way to widen the display of output in either interactive or script-execution mode?

Specifically, I am using the `describe()` function on a Pandas `DataFrame`.  When the `DataFrame` is five columns (labels) wide, I get the descriptive statistics that I want.  However, if the `DataFrame` has any more columns, the statistics are suppressed and something like this is returned:

```
>> Index: 8 entries, count to max
>> Data columns:
>> x1          8  non-null values
>> x2          8  non-null values
>> x3          8  non-null values
>> x4          8  non-null values
>> x5          8  non-null values
>> x6          8  non-null values
>> x7          8  non-null values
```

The "8" value is given whether there are 6 or 7 columns.  What does the "8" refer to?

I have already tried dragging the [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) window larger, as well as increasing the "Configure IDLE" width options, to no avail.

Comment: [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) is the user guide 'options and settings' from pandas with examples you are looking for.

Answer (score 1462, accepted):

**Update: Pandas 0.23.4 onwards**

This is not necessary. Pandas autodetects the size of your terminal window if you set `pd.options.display.width = 0`. (For older versions see at bottom.)

`pandas.set_printoptions(...)` is deprecated. Instead, use `pandas.set_option(optname, val)`, or equivalently `pd.options.<opt.hierarchical.name> = val`. Like:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Here is the [help for `set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html):

```
set_option(pat,value) - Sets the value of the specified option

Available options:
display.[chop_threshold, colheader_justify, column_space, date_dayfirst,
         date_yearfirst, encoding, expand_frame_repr, float_format, height,
         line_width, max_columns, max_colwidth, max_info_columns, max_info_rows,
         max_rows, max_seq_items, mpl_style, multi_sparse, notebook_repr_html,
         pprint_nest_depth, precision, width]
mode.[sim_interactive, use_inf_as_null]

Parameters
----------
pat - str/regexp which should match a single option.

Note: partial matches are supported for convenience, but unless you use the
full option name (e.g., *x.y.z.option_name*), your code may break in future
versions if new options with similar names are introduced.

value - new value of option.

Returns
-------
None

Raises
------
KeyError if no such option exists

display.chop_threshold: [default: None] [currently: None]
: float or None
        if set to a float value, all float values smaller then the given threshold
        will be displayed as exactly 0 by repr and friends.
display.colheader_justify: [default: right] [currently: right]
: 'left'/'right'
        Controls the justification of column headers. used by DataFrameFormatter.
display.column_space: [default: 12] [currently: 12]No description available.

display.date_dayfirst: [default: False] [currently: False]
: boolean
        When True, prints and parses dates with the day first, eg 20/01/2005
display.date_yearfirst: [default: False] [currently: False]
: boolean
        When True, prints and parses dates with the year first, e.g., 2005/01/20
display.encoding: [default: UTF-8] [currently: UTF-8]
: str/unicode
        Defaults to the detected encoding of the console.
        Specifies the encoding to be used for strings returned by to_string,
        these are generally strings meant to be displayed on the console.
display.expand_frame_repr: [default: True] [currently: True]
: boolean
        Whether to print out the full DataFrame repr for wide DataFrames
        across multiple lines, `max_columns` is still respected, but the output will
        wrap-around across multiple "pages" if it's width exceeds `display.width`.
display.float_format: [default: None] [currently: None]
: callable
        The callable should accept a floating point number and return
        a string with the desired format of the number. This is used
        in some places like SeriesFormatter.
        See core.format.EngFormatter for an example.
display.height: [default: 60] [currently: 1000]
: int
        Deprecated.
        (Deprecated, use `display.height` instead.)

display.line_width: [default: 80] [currently: 1000]
: int
        Deprecated.
        (Deprecated, use `display.width` instead.)

display.max_columns: [default: 20] [currently: 500]
: int
        max_rows and max_columns are used in __repr__() methods to decide if
        to_string() or info() is used to render an object to a string.  In case
        python/IPython is running in a terminal this can be set to 0 and Pandas
        will correctly auto-detect the width the terminal and swap to a smaller
        format in case all columns would not fit vertically. The IPython notebook,
        IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a terminal and hence it is not
        possible to do correct auto-detection.
        'None' value means unlimited.
display.max_colwidth: [default: 50] [currently: 50]
: int
        The maximum width in characters of a column in the repr of
        a Pandas data structure. When the column overflows, a "..."
        placeholder is embedded in the output.
display.max_info_columns: [default: 100] [currently: 100]
: int
        max_info_columns is used in DataFrame.info method to decide if
        per column information will be printed.
display.max_info_rows: [default: 1690785] [currently: 1690785]
: int or None
        max_info_rows is the maximum number of rows for which a frame will
        perform a null check on its columns when repr'ing To a console.
        The default is 1,000,000 rows. So, if a DataFrame has more
        1,000,000 rows there will be no null check performed on the
        columns and thus the representation will take much less time to
        display in an interactive session. A value of None means always
        perform a null check when repr'ing.
display.max_rows: [default: 60] [currently: 500]
: int
        This sets the maximum number of rows Pandas should output when printing
        out various output. For example, this value determines whether the repr()
        for a dataframe prints out fully or just a summary repr.
        'None' value means unlimited.
display.max_seq_items: [default: None] [currently: None]
: int or None

        when pretty-printing a long sequence, no more then `max_seq_items`
        will be printed. If items are ommitted, they will be denoted by the addition
        of "..." to the resulting string.

        If set to None, the number of items to be printed is unlimited.
display.mpl_style: [default: None] [currently: None]
: bool

        Setting this to 'default' will modify the rcParams used by matplotlib
        to give plots a more pleasing visual style by default.
        Setting this to None/False restores the values to their initial value.
display.multi_sparse: [default: True] [currently: True]
: boolean
        "sparsify" MultiIndex display (don't display repeated
        elements in outer levels within groups)
display.notebook_repr_html: [default: True] [currently: True]
: boolean
        When True, IPython notebook will use html representation for
        Pandas objects (if it is available).
display.pprint_nest_depth: [default: 3] [currently: 3]
: int
        Controls the number of nested levels to process when pretty-printing
display.precision: [default: 7] [currently: 7]
: int
        Floating point output precision (number of significant digits). This is
        only a suggestion
display.width: [default: 80] [currently: 1000]
: int
        Width of the display in characters. In case python/IPython is running in
        a terminal this can be set to None and Pandas will correctly auto-detect the
        width.
        Note that the IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a
        terminal and hence it is not possible to correctly detect the width.
mode.sim_interactive: [default: False] [currently: False]
: boolean
        Whether to simulate interactive mode for purposes of testing
mode.use_inf_as_null: [default: False] [currently: False]
: boolean
        True means treat None, NaN, INF, -INF as null (old way),
        False means None and NaN are null, but INF, -INF are not null
        (new way).
Call def:   pd.set_option(self, *args, **kwds)
```

---

Older version information. Much of this has been deprecated.

As @bmu [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11708664/623735), Pandas auto detects (by default) the size of the display area, a summary view will be used when an object repr does not fit on the display. You mentioned resizing the IDLE window, to no effect. If you do `print df.describe().to_string()` does it fit on the IDLE window?

The terminal size is determined by `pandas.util.terminal.get_terminal_size()` (deprecated and removed), this returns a tuple containing the `(width, height)` of the display. Does the output match the size of your IDLE window? There might be an issue (there was one before when running a terminal in Emacs).

Note that it is possible to bypass the autodetect, `pandas.set_printoptions(max_rows=200, max_columns=10)` will never switch to summary view if number of rows, columns does not exceed the given limits.

---

The 'max_colwidth' option helps in seeing untruncated form of each column.

[image: TruncatedColumnDisplay]

Comment: Equivalent to the answer
`import pandas as pd`
`pd.options.display.width = 1000`
`pd.options.display.max_rows = 500`
`pd.options.display.max_columns = 500`

Comment: Pandas did not auto-detect the size of my window with `pd.options.display.width = 0`, but `pd.options.display.width = 1000` worked.

Answer (score 282):

Try this:

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

From the documentation:

> display.expand_frame_repr : boolean
>
> Whether to print out the full DataFrame repr for wide DataFrames across multiple lines, max_columns is still respected, but the output will wrap-around across multiple “pages” if it’s width exceeds display.width. [default: True] [currently: True]

See: *[pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html)*.

Answer (score 262):

If you want to set options temporarily to display one large DataFrame, you can use [option_context](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html):

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print (df)
```

Option values are restored automatically when you exit the `with` block.

Answer (score 187):

Only using these three lines worked for me:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)
```

It was for [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), Python 3.6.5, Pandas 0.23.0, and Visual Studio Code 1.26.

Comment: <ipython-input-40-af12a43ad140>:3: FutureWarning: Passing a negative integer is deprecated in version 1.0 and will not be supported in future version. Instead, use None to not limit the column width.
  pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)

Answer (score 84):

Set the column maximum width using:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)
```

This particular statement sets the maximum width to 800 pixels per column.

Comment: Scrolling down in descending vote order, this is the first answer that worked for me to get pandas to not truncate the plaintext output of DataFrames. (pandas 0.22, iTerm2 3.0.13, OS X 10.12).

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me for Pandas 0.23.2.

Comment: How come you didn't have to specify it as `display.max_colwidth`?  That is how it is listed in the documentation.  I agree that only `max_colwidth` works and is shorter to write, but I was surprised.

Answer (score 34):

I used these settings when the scale of the data was high.

```
# Environment settings: 
pd.set_option('display.max_column', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
```

You can refer to the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html).

Comment: This was only one that worked using Powershell / Windows / Pandas 1.5.1 / Python 3.10.1

Answer (score 30):

You can use `print df.describe().to_string()` to force it to show the whole table.  (You can use `to_string()` like this for any DataFrame.  The result of `describe` is just a DataFrame itself.)

The 8 is the number of rows in the DataFrame holding the "description" (because `describe` computes 8 statistics, min, max, mean, etc.).

Answer (score 29):

You can adjust Pandas print options with `set_printoptions`.

```
In [3]: df.describe()
Out[3]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 8 entries, count to max
Data columns:
x1    8  non-null values
x2    8  non-null values
x3    8  non-null values
x4    8  non-null values
x5    8  non-null values
x6    8  non-null values
x7    8  non-null values
dtypes: float64(7)

In [4]: pd.set_printoptions(precision=2)

In [5]: df.describe()
Out[5]:
            x1       x2       x3       x4       x5       x6       x7
count      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0
mean   69024.5  69025.5  69026.5  69027.5  69028.5  69029.5  69030.5
std       17.1     17.1     17.1     17.1     17.1     17.1     17.1
min    69000.0  69001.0  69002.0  69003.0  69004.0  69005.0  69006.0
25%    69012.2  69013.2  69014.2  69015.2  69016.2  69017.2  69018.2
50%    69024.5  69025.5  69026.5  69027.5  69028.5  69029.5  69030.5
75%    69036.8  69037.8  69038.8  69039.8  69040.8  69041.8  69042.8
max    69049.0  69050.0  69051.0  69052.0  69053.0  69054.0  69055.0
```

However, this will not work in all cases as Pandas detects your console width, and it will only use `to_string` if the output fits in the console (see the docstring of `set_printoptions`).
In this case, you can explicitly call `to_string` as answered by [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11707706/1301710).

**Update**

With version 0.10 the way wide dataframes are printed [changed](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#wide-dataframe-print):

```
In [3]: df.describe()
Out[3]:
                 x1            x2            x3            x4            x5  \
count      8.000000      8.000000      8.000000      8.000000      8.000000
mean   59832.361578  27356.711336  49317.281222  51214.837838  51254.839690
std    22600.723536  26867.192716  28071.737509  21012.422793  33831.515761
min    31906.695474   1648.359160     56.378115  16278.322271     43.745574
25%    45264.625201  12799.540572  41429.628749  40374.273582  29789.643875
50%    56340.214856  18666.456293  51995.661512  54894.562656  47667.684422
75%    75587.003417  31375.610322  61069.190523  67811.893435  76014.884048
max    98136.474782  84544.484627  91743.983895  75154.587156  99012.695717

                 x6            x7
count      8.000000      8.000000
mean   41863.000717  33950.235126
std    38709.468281  29075.745673
min     3590.990740   1833.464154
25%    15145.759625   6879.523949
50%    22139.243042  33706.029946
75%    72038.983496  51449.893980
max    98601.190488  83309.051963
```

Furthermore, the API for setting Pandas options changed:

```
In [4]: pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)

In [5]: df.describe()
Out[5]:
            x1       x2       x3       x4       x5       x6       x7
count      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0      8.0
mean   59832.4  27356.7  49317.3  51214.8  51254.8  41863.0  33950.2
std    22600.7  26867.2  28071.7  21012.4  33831.5  38709.5  29075.7
min    31906.7   1648.4     56.4  16278.3     43.7   3591.0   1833.5
25%    45264.6  12799.5  41429.6  40374.3  29789.6  15145.8   6879.5
50%    56340.2  18666.5  51995.7  54894.6  47667.7  22139.2  33706.0
75%    75587.0  31375.6  61069.2  67811.9  76014.9  72039.0  51449.9
max    98136.5  84544.5  91744.0  75154.6  99012.7  98601.2  83309.1
```

Answer (score 29):

The below line is enough to display all columns from a dataframe.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a new answer to a question and there are some more answers, try to show the Pros. There is still one answer `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 0)` Which ones are the benefits of yours?

Answer (score 25):

You can set the output display to match your current terminal width:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', pd.util.terminal.get_terminal_size()[0])
```

Comment: this no longer works

Answer (score 20):

**You can simply do the following steps,**

- You can change the options for the Pandas *max_columns* feature as follows:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  pd.options.display.max_columns = 10
  ```

  (This allows 10 columns to display, and you can change this as you need.)
- Like that, you can change the number of rows that you need to display as follows (if you need to change maximum rows as well):

  ```
  pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
  ```

  (This allows to print 999 rows at a time.)

Please kindly refer to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) to change different options/settings for Pandas.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [documentation for v0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html), if you're running in a terminal (i.e., not [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) notebook, qtconsole or [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE)), it's a two-liner to have Pandas autodetect your screen width and adapt on the fly with how many columns it shows:

```
pd.set_option('display.large_repr', 'truncate')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 0)
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I'm using Pandas 0.22.0 (latest as of Feb 8 2018) using the built-in Terminal app on OS X 10.11.6

Comment: What if you are running in a notebook?

Answer (score 12):

It seems like all the previous answers solve the problem. One more point: instead of `pd.set_option('option_name')`, you can use the (auto-complete-able):

```
pd.options.display.width = None
```

See [Pandas documentation: *Options and settings*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html):

> Options have a full “dotted-style”, case-insensitive name (e.g.
> `display.max_rows`). You can get/set options directly as attributes of
> the top-level `options` attribute:
>
> ```
> In [1]: import pandas as pd
>
> In [2]: pd.options.display.max_rows
> Out[2]: 15
>
> In [3]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
>
> In [4]: pd.options.display.max_rows
> Out[4]: 999
> ```

[...]

For the `max_...` parameters:

> `max_rows` and `max_columns` are used in `__repr__()` methods to decide if `to_string()` or `info()` is used to render an object to a string. In case Python/[IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) is running in a terminal this can be set to 0 and pandas will correctly auto-detect the width the terminal and swap to a smaller format in case all columns would not fit vertically. The IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a terminal and hence it is not possible to do correct auto-detection. **‘`None`’ value means unlimited.** [emphasis not in original]

For the `width` parameter:

> Width of the display in characters. In case Python/IPython is running in a terminal this can be set to `None` and pandas will correctly auto-detect the width. Note that the IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) do not run in a terminal and hence it is not possible to correctly detect the width.

Answer (score 12):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

SentenceA = "William likes Piano and Piano likes William"
SentenceB = "Sara likes Guitar"
SentenceC = "Mamoosh likes Piano"
SentenceD = "William is a CS Student"
SentenceE = "Sara is kind"
SentenceF = "Mamoosh is kind"


bowA = SentenceA.split(" ")
bowB = SentenceB.split(" ")
bowC = SentenceC.split(" ")
bowD = SentenceD.split(" ")
bowE = SentenceE.split(" ")
bowF = SentenceF.split(" ")

# Creating a set consisting of all words

wordSet = set(bowA).union(set(bowB)).union(set(bowC)).union(set(bowD)).union(set(bowE)).union(set(bowF))
print("Set of all words is: ", wordSet)

# Initiating dictionary with 0 value for all BOWs

wordDictA = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)
wordDictB = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)
wordDictC = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)
wordDictD = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)
wordDictE = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)
wordDictF = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)

for word in bowA:
    wordDictA[word] += 1
for word in bowB:
    wordDictB[word] += 1
for word in bowC:
    wordDictC[word] += 1
for word in bowD:
    wordDictD[word] += 1
for word in bowE:
    wordDictE[word] += 1
for word in bowF:
    wordDictF[word] += 1

# Printing term frequency

print("SentenceA TF: ", wordDictA)
print("SentenceB TF: ", wordDictB)
print("SentenceC TF: ", wordDictC)
print("SentenceD TF: ", wordDictD)
print("SentenceE TF: ", wordDictE)
print("SentenceF TF: ", wordDictF)

print(pd.DataFrame([wordDictA, wordDictB, wordDictB, wordDictC, wordDictD, wordDictE, wordDictF]))
```

Output:

```
   CS  Guitar  Mamoosh  Piano  Sara  Student  William  a  and  is  kind  likes
0   0       0        0      2     0        0        2  0    1   0     0      2
1   0       1        0      0     1        0        0  0    0   0     0      1
2   0       1        0      0     1        0        0  0    0   0     0      1
3   0       0        1      1     0        0        0  0    0   0     0      1
4   1       0        0      0     0        1        1  1    0   1     0      0
5   0       0        0      0     1        0        0  0    0   1     1      0
6   0       0        1      0     0        0        0  0    0   1     1      0
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this custom function for displaying things for a Pandas `Dataframe`.

```
def display_all(df):     # For any Dataframe df
   with pd.option_context('display.max_rows',1000): # Change number of rows accordingly
      with pd.option_context('display.max_columns',1000): # Change number of columns accordingly
          display(df)
```

`display_all(df.head()) # Pass this function to your dataframe and voilà!`

You don't have to use `pd.set_option` for the whole notebook just using for a single cell.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to mess with your display options and you just want to see this one particular list of columns without expanding out every dataframe you view, you could try:

```
df.columns.values
```

Answer (score 3):

The below will increase the width when **NumPy** arrays are printed.

It gave good results in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=120)
```

For increasing the print area for **pandas** objects (eg: Index):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', 120)
```

Answer (score 3):

To use context in notebook,

```py
from IPython.display import display

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,
                       'display.max_columns', None):
    display(df)
```

*based on [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375383/11671779)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try in a loop:

```
for col in df.columns: 
    print(col)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., how does that answer the question *"Is there a way to widen the display of output in either interactive or script-execution mode?"*

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = 100
```

You can specify the numbers of columns as per your requirement in max_columns.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers were working for me. A couple of them would indeed print all the columns, but it would look sloppy. As in all the information was there, but it wasn't formatted correctly. I'm using a terminal inside of [Neovim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Neovim) so I suspect that to be the reason.

This mini function does exactly what I need, just change `df_data` in the two places it is for your dataframe name (`col_range` is set to what pandas naturally shows, for me it is 5 but it could be bigger or smaller for you).

```
import math
col_range = 5
for _ in range(int(math.ceil(len(df_data.columns)/col_range))):
    idx1 = _*col_range
    idx2 = idx1+col_range
    print(df_data.iloc[:, idx1:idx2].describe())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the answer strictly speaking, but let's remember we can `df.describe().transpose()` or even `df.head(n).transpose()`, or `df.tail(n).transpose()`.

I also find it easier to read headers as a column when they are structured:

header1_xxx,

header2_xxx,

header3_xxx,

I think terminals and applications handle the vertical scrolling more naturally, if this is necessary after transposing.

Headers are commonly larger than their values, having all of them in one column (index) minimizes their impact on the total table width.

Finally other df descriptions can be merged as well, here is a possible idea:

```
def df_overview(df: pd.DataFrame, max_colwidth=25, head=3, tail=3):
    return(
        df.describe([0.5]).transpose()
        .merge(df.dtypes.rename('dtypes'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
        .merge(df.head(head).transpose(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
        .merge(df.tail(tail).transpose(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
        .to_string(max_colwidth=max_colwidth, float_format=lambda x: "{:.4G}".format(x))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all rows of a particular column, you just need to select the dataframe with the column name and then use the tolist method.

```
pd['column_name'].tolist()
```

This will convert pandas series to a python list.