# How to configure display output in IPython pandas

Tags: python, terminal, pandas, ipython

I'm trying to configure my IPython output in my OS X terminal, but it would seem that none of the changes I'm trying to set are taking effect. I'm trying to configure the display settings such that wider outputs like a big `DataFrame` will output without any truncation or as the summary info.

After importing pandas into my script, I have a few options set where I tried a whole bunch, but any one (or all, for that matter) does not seem to take effect. I'm running the script from IPython using `%run`. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.expand_max_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 30)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.line_width', 200)
```

I've looked at [some threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-widen-output-display) on Stack and the [pandas FAQ](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/faq.html) to no avail, even when using these under the display namespace (or without), as I've attempted here.

I understand that there are some ways around this, such as calling `to_string()` or `describe()` methods on your output, but these are very manual, and don't always work as intended in some cases, like one where I have calling `to_string()` on a `groupby` object yields:

```
    id       type
106125       puzzle       gameplay_id  sitting_id  user_id           ...
106253       frames       gameplay_id  sitting_id  user_id           ...
106260       trivia       gameplay_id  sitting_id  user_id           ...
```

My terminal window size is more than sufficient to accommodate the width, and calling `pd.util.terminal.get_terminal_size()` is correctly finding the window size tuple, so it would seem that auto detecting the size isn't working either. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using iPython Notebook? You can render dataframes in HTML which allows you to view untruncated versions of your data.

Comment: yeah this sounds interesting, I haven't really considered it until now (I'm new to pandas). Do you know of a good resource to get it up and running?

Comment: Umm... gosh its been so long since I installed it. You basically install iPython and then in the command line type ipython notebook. Its an incredibly useful tool, you can write markdown, include graphs, pictures, videos, HTML, LaTex etc. Its quite remarkable. For data workflow it simply cannot be beaten in my opinion. I prepared this notebook for my organisation that shows some of what iPython can do... http://goo.gl/1Vneam Its really not hard to get up and running.

Comment: turned out to be relatively easy with anaconda (comes packaged with it), so I'm up and running with notebook now. Just needed to run a few updates on conda and even got a prompt to update pip in the process ;)

Comment: Enjoy... I love the notebooks!

Comment: When you are up and running simply `from IPython.core.display import HTML` and then `HTML(df.to_html())`

Comment: @WoodyPride thanks for the primer on the notebook =)

Comment: @Chrispy you missed out max_colwidth ... it looks like you have a long column?

Comment: @AndyHayden I'm honestly not sure. Should it be `set_option('display.max_colwidth', 200)`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just for completeness (I'll add my comment as an answer), you missed out:

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth  # default is 50
```

*this restricted the maximum length of a single column.*

There are quite a few options to configure here, if you're using ipython then tab complete to find the [full set of display options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options):

```
pd.options.display.<tab>
```

Comment: Andy -- When try setting `display.max_colwidth=None` in `master`, I get `ValueError: Value must have type '<type 'int'>'`. Any thoughts on how to remove this limit (in the same way `None` removes limits for other options?)

Comment: @user815423426 have you tried display.max_colwidth=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution works well for strings but not for the columns with numbers. In that case to get the correct width, the format can be changed with:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:15.10f}'.format)
```

Also, to change the display just once and not for the whole notebook:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None):
    print(df)  # or display(df)
```