# Pandas and NumPy default width change on startup

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython

Is there a way to specify Pandas and NumPy display width on startup of an IPython shell. For example,

```
# Run this at startup
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)

import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = 200
```

Comment: Here is for pandas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249206/how-to-configure-display-output-in-ipython-pandas

Comment: It is not clear to me that the Pandas config will let you do all of this. It may be easier to just use the PYTHONSTARTUP environmental variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124578/automatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter

Comment: @andrew The link you provided also had a way to put a startup script in .ipython profile directory as shown in the answer below. Thanks

Comment: Great. I was thinking more along the lines of the IPython profiles and configurations. But the solution below accomplishes the same thing as using PYTHONPATH.
http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html?highlight=config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, for me, I have a startup directory:

```
'C:\Users\username\.ipython\profile_default\startup'
```

In this I create a file:

```
'00-script.py`
```

Files in this directory will be run in alphabetical order by name. I put '00' in front to ensure it gets run first. In this file, you'd put:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)

import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = 200
```

Check documentation to see where your directory is.

[Documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html#ipythondir)

Comment: Don't make fun. I'm forced to. Home is different.

Comment: ha! fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer by @piRSquared, on Unix-based systems, you can do it by putting a startup script in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`:

```
$ cat ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/load_pdnp.py 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.display.width = 200
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
```

Or `~/.ipython/profile_<name>/startup` for a specific profile.

This has a side effect that `pd` and `np` would be now available to you in the IPython shell.