# How can I save pandas display options for further sessions?

Tags: pandas

I'm getting a bit tired of running `pd.options.display.max_columns = some_large_number` for every new session.

Is there a way to save my preferences permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [panda's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment), you can create a startup file.
You can find examples on how to set up these startup files [here (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125085/2806632) and [here (ipython)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489295/2806632).

Basically make your `startup.py` like:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', some_large_number)
```

And put it in *ipython's* `profile_default` or link it with the `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable for regular *python*.