# Pandas 'describe' is not returning summary of all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am running 'describe()' on a dataframe and getting summaries of only int columns (pandas 14.0).

The documentation says that for object columns frequency of most common value, and additional statistics would be returned. What could be wrong? (no error message is returned by the way)

**Edit:**

I think it's how the function is set to behave on mixed column types in a dataframe. Although the documentation fails to mention it.

**Example code:**

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'$a':[1,2], '$b': [10,20]})
df_test.dtypes
df_test.describe()
df_test['$a'] = df_test['$a'].astype(str)
df_test.describe()
df_test['$a'].describe()
df_test['$b'].describe()
```

**My ugly work around in the meanwhile:**

```
def my_df_describe(df):
    objects = []
    numerics = []
    for c in df:
        if (df[c].dtype == object):
            objects.append(c)
        else:
            numerics.append(c)

    return df[numerics].describe(), df[objects].describe()
```

Comment: It is not meaningful to calculate things like mean, std etc.. for object dtypes such as string and datetime, this is probably what you are seeing. You should see summary info for ints and float columns

Comment: Actually the problem I am noticing is only for mixed (int/object) dataframes...

Comment: You mean a specific column has mixed dtypes?

Comment: No, different columns have different dtypes. I have added an example and it can be seen how describe after the type change differs from the one before it. I would of expected to have both stats (object and int) in the same dataframe with null values in parts where the statistics can not be computed for the column (e.g., std for object types)

Comment: I ran your code and don't understand what the problem is, like I said there is no point display stats for objects like string, I understand that if you called describe just on the string column it shows count and unique when it didn't before, you could raise this as a feature request but I imagine it would look ugly and unwieldly if you had a dataframe with lots of varying types and try to format the output to take into considertaion all the different dtypes

Comment: It's possible this is a bug perhaps, you'd have to either look at the source code or wait for one of the devs to look at this question and comment, not sure I remember if this behaviour changed between 11.0 to 14.0

Comment: ok thank you, just wrote an ugly work around to suit my needs...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As of pandas v15.0, use the parameter, [**`DataFrame.describe(include = 'all')`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) to get a summary of all the columns when the dataframe has *mixed column types*. The default behavior is to only provide a summary for the numerical columns.

**Example:**

```
In[1]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], '$b': np.arange(5)})
df.describe(include = 'all')

Out[1]:

        $a    $b
count   5   5.000000
unique  4   NaN
top     a   NaN
freq    2   NaN
mean    NaN 2.000000
std     NaN 1.581139
min     NaN 0.000000
25%     NaN 1.000000
50%     NaN 2.000000
75%     NaN 3.000000
max     NaN 4.000000
```

The numerical columns will have NaNs for summary statistics pertaining to objects (strings) and vice versa.

**Summarizing only numerical or object columns**

1. To call `describe()` on just the numerical columns use `describe(include = [np.number])`
2. To call `describe()` on just the objects (strings) using `describe(include = ['O'])`.

   ```
   In[2]:

   df.describe(include = [np.number])

   Out[3]:

            $b
   count   5.000000
   mean    2.000000
   std     1.581139
   min     0.000000
   25%     1.000000
   50%     2.000000
   75%     3.000000
   max     4.000000

   In[3]:

   df.describe(include = ['O'])

   Out[3]:

       $a
   count   5
   unique  4
   top     a
   freq    2
   ```

Comment: All columns are *still* not displayed.

Answer (score 21):

`pd.options.display.max_columns = DATA.shape[1]` will work.

Here `DATA` is a 2d matrix, and above code will display stats vertically.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the data type issues discussed in the other answers, you might also have too many columns to display.  If there are too many columns, the middle columns will be replaced with a total of three dots (`...`).

Other answers have pointed out that the `include='all'` parameter of `describe` can help with the data type issue.  Another question asked, "[How do I expand the output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586#11711637)"  The solution is to modify the `display.max_columns` setting, which can even be done [temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586#33375383).  For example, to display up to 40 columns of output from a single `describe` statement:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 40):
    print(df.describe(include='all'))
```

Answer (score 5):

'describe()' on a DataFrame only works for numeric types. If you think you have a numeric variable and it doesn't show up in 'decribe()', change the type with:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].astype(float)
```

You could also create new columns for handling the numeric part of a mix type column, or convert strings to numbers using a dictionary and the map() function.

'describe()' on a non-numerical Series will give you some statistics (like count, unique and the most frequently occurring value).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `DataFrame.describe(include = 'all')` one can also use `Series.value_counts()` for each categorical column:

```
In[1]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'$a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], '$b': np.arange(5)})
df['$a'].value_counts()

Out[1]:
$a
a    2
d    1
b    1
c    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute `df_test.info()` to get the list of datatypes your data frame contains.If your data frame contains only numerical columns than df_test.describe() will work perfectly fine.As by default, it provides the summary of numerical values. If you want the summary of your Object(String) features you can use `df_test.describe(include=['O'])`.

Or in short, you can just use `df_test.describe(include='all')` to get summary of all the feature columns when your data frame has columns of various data types.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.astype(float)
df.describe()
```

It is likely that you are just reading your data from `pd.read_csv` instead of saving it as DataFrame. If you have any headers in columns, do this

```
df = df[1:]
```

This worked for me