# Summarize categorical data in Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, dask

By default `describe` method of Dask DataFrame summarizes only numerical columns. According to the [docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.describe) I should be able to get descriptions of categorical columns by providing `include` parameter. However

`df.describe(include=['category']).compute()`

leads to a

`TypeError: describe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'`.

I tried also a little different approach:

`df.select_dtypes(include=['category']).describe().compute()`

and this time I get

`ValueError: DataFrame contains only non-numeric data.`

Could you please advise what would be the best way to summarize categorical columns in Dask DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

**Summarizing only numerical or object columns**

1. To call describe() on just the numerical columns use
   describe(include = [np.number])
2. To call describe() on just the objects (strings) using
   describe(include = ['O']).

Quote: [Pandas 'describe' is not returning summary of all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524104/pandas-describe-is-not-returning-summary-of-all-columns)