# WinPython/Spyder IDE console linebreak issue

Tags: python, console, spyder

My problem can be seen on this image:
[image]

So the problem is, that Spyder break the line and my output can't be display in "one" line. How can I change this?

Comment: Write shorter lines? Use a different interpreter?

Comment: It must be an option to write wider lines than e.g. 400 px.

How to change interpreter?
I am usint IPython and standard Python consoles

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) Spyder doesn't break lines in its Python or IPython consoles.

You don't say explicitly, but it seems your image is the result of printing a Pandas DataFrame.

If that's the case, please see this answer:

[Python pandas, how to widen output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-widen-output-display)

Answer (score 1):

This solves your question:
pd.set_option('display.width', 170)

You can try different numbers from 170, until you are satisfied with the outupt you want in your Spyder console.