# python - pandas library print format

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix

I am using pandas library to calculate confussion matrix, but the problem is that my categories have about 10 characters and only 3-4 columns are displayed, even though values in those columns are greater than 0. Is it possible to increase maximum width of displayed matrix ?

Comment: Related: [Python pandas, widen output display?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11707586/190597)

Comment: Yes, you can widen output display. I also thing you might want to use abbreviated column names like `df.rename(columns=lambda x : x[:3])`