# How to columnate a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, multiple-columns

I have a `pandas Series`, sufficiently small so I can read all items (about 80), but too big for the size of the screen.

Is there some `python` command ou `ipython` (notebook) magic command or `pandas` function to columnate that `list` or `Series` so I can read it entirely without scrolling down and up?

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of the `column` command in `bash`.

For example, I have a `Series` like this:

```
A      76
B      56
C      42
D      31
E      31
F      25
G      24
```

And let's say that my screen is so small that I need to scroll down to see after the `B` row. What I'd like is something like this:

```
A    76        C    42        E    31        G    24
B    56        D    31        F    25
```

Comment: have a look at that question and the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-widen-output-display Is this what you want to do?

Comment: No, this is what I'm doing now to display more than X rows. The thing is that I have 1 column, and I'd like it displayed with multiple columns so all data can fit in the screen.

Comment: What is the "screen"? Is it a terminal? Is it HTML? Is the number of columns in a terminal always going to be consistent?

Comment: The screen is the size the window of the terminal or of the ipython notebook page.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd think about looking to numpy for a solution as numpy output does tend more towards this style of output (though obviously what it is missing are the indexes)

Comment: @JohnE Maybe, but if the output formatting in the interactive console is so important to change the framework for the data, wouldn't it make more sense to write some `print_nice` function and really `print` the data?

Comment: @chris-sc  Sure.  Just looking for something easier than that, but may not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following non-numpy/pandas solution might give you some inspiration:

```
import itertools

rows =  [("A", 76),  ("B", 56), ("C", 42), ("D", 31), ("E", 31), ("F", 25), ("G", 24)]

def print_multi_cols(lrows, split_at=5, space_each=4):
    for row in itertools.izip(*itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(lrows)]*split_at, fillvalue=(" ", " "))):
        for col in row:
            print " ".join(["%-*s" % (space_each, item) for item in col]),
        print

print_multi_cols(rows, 2)
print_multi_cols(rows, 3)
```

This gives the following output:

```
A     76      C     42      E     31      G     24     
B     56      D     31      F     25                   

A     76      D     31      G     24     
B     56      E     31                   
C     42      F     25
```

You would need to convert your series before this could be used. Tested using Python 2.7.

Or for a bit more control over the justification, it could be modified as follows:

```
import itertools

rows =  [("A", 9),  ("B", 56), ("C", 42), ("D", 31), ("E", 31), ("F", 25), ("G", 999)]

def print_multi_cols(lrows, split_at=5, space_each=4, left_justify=None):
    if not left_justify:
        left_justify = [True] * len(lrows[0])

    for row in itertools.izip(*itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(lrows)]*split_at, fillvalue=(" ", " "))):
        for col in row:
            print " ".join([("%-*s " if left else "%*s ") % (space_each, item) for item, left in itertools.izip(col, left_justify)]),
        print
    print

print_multi_cols(rows, split_at=5, space_each=3, left_justify=[True, False])
```

Giving:

```
A      9  F     25 
B     56  G    999 
C     42           
D     31           
E     31
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks what I want. To pass a `Series` object you need to do `my_series.reset_index().values`. There may be a nicer way to pass the Series but I couldn't find. Thanks anyway, I'll wait before accepting in case someone comes with another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using the idea of a `show` function (with some loops, but since data that can be shown that way is small, it should be fine).

```
def show(series, cols=6):                                                        
    rows = int(np.ceil(len(series)/float(cols)))                                 
    indices = series.index                                                       

    ind_loop = 0                                                                 
    for row in range(rows):                                                      
        ind = indices[ind_loop:ind_loop+cols]                                    
        dat = series[ind]                                                        
        comb = zip(ind, dat)                                                     
        print_str = ""                                                           
        for num in range(len(dat)):                                              
            print_str += "{{{0}: <10}} ".format(num)                             

        print(print_str.format(*comb))                                           
        ind_loop += cols                                                         

ser = pd.Series(range(20))                                                                                                                                                        
show(ser, cols=6) 

(0, 0)     (1, 1)     (2, 2)     (3, 3)     (4, 4)     (5, 5)                     
(6, 6)     (7, 7)     (8, 8)     (9, 9)     (10, 10)   (11, 11)
(12, 12)   (13, 13)   (14, 14)   (15, 15)   (16, 16)   (17, 17)
(18, 18)   (19, 19)
```

You could adjust the `print` to show something like `index : value` if you like.