# How to copy/paste a dataframe from iPython into Google Sheets or Excel?

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've been using iPython (aka Jupyter) quite a bit lately for data analysis and some machine learning. But one big headache is copying results from the notebook app (browser) into either Excel or Google Sheets so I can manipulate results or share them with people who don't use iPython.

I know how to convert results to csv and save. But then I have to dig through my computer, open the results and paste them into Excel or Google Sheets. That takes too much time.

And just highlighting a resulting dataframe and copy/pasting usually completely messes up the formatting, with columns overflowing. (Not to mention the issue of long resulting dataframes being truncated when printed in iPython.)

How can I easily copy/paste an iPython result into a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try using the to_clipboard() method. E.g., for a dataframe, df: **df.to_clipboard()** will copy said dataframe to your clipboard. You can then paste it into Excel or Google Docs.

Comment: When I try this I get everything in a single column in google sheets.  Same in Excel but I can use text>columns.  This is on OS X.  I thought it used to work in previous versions of pandas (currently on 0.18.0) but maybe I'm imagining that.

Comment: @patricksurry Although the docs say excel=True is the default, I had to enable it explicilty: `df.to_clipboard(excel=True,sep='\t')`

Comment: @patricksurry Indeed, [the docs and code are inconsistent](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L2191-L2246). Anyone want to submit a bug report or patch?

Answer (score 8):

If `df.to_clipboard` doesn't work. This will work.

```
import io
with io.StringIO() as buffer:
    df.to_csv(buffer, sep=' ', index=False)
    print(buffer.getvalue())
```

Then, you can copy the printed dataframe and paste it in Excel or Google Sheets.

Comment: This pastes all columns of each row to a single cell, any way to paste also the columns?

Comment: I had to "paste special" in Excel and choose "text", then a simple copy-paste from Jupyter notebook output to Excel, works (both rows and columns)

Answer (score 3):

I use `display()` instead of `print()` and it works fine for me. Example:

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd

dict = {'Name' : ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
        'English' : [73, 55, 90],
        'Math' : [78, 100, 33],
        'Geography' : [92, 87, 72]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

display(df)
```

The result can easily be copied and pasted into Excel and formatting won't be messed up. This method also works with Colab.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the output to an IDE like Atom and then paste in Google Sheets/Excel

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make the csv or html available and reachable by a url - you can use this in google sheets.

```
=IMPORTDATA("url to the csv/html file")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I might make results of a script reachable by url. Any help with that?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience SpreadSheet uses tabulation (\t) to separate cells and newline (\n) to separate rows.

Assuming this I wrote a simple function to convert from clipboard data:

```
def from_excel_to_list(copy_text):
    """Use it to copy and paste data from SpreadSheet software
    (MS Excel, Libreoffice) and convert to a list
    """
    if isinstance(copy_text, str):
        array = []
        rows = copy_text.split("\n")  # splits rows
        for row in rows:
            if len(row):  # removes empty lines
                array.append(row.split("\t"))
        return array
    else:
        raise TypeError("text must be string")
```

You can define the function inside Jupiter and use it in this way:

Copy with ctrl-c on the SpreadSheet and than call the function from_excel_to_list pasting the data with ctrl-v inside the double brackets

```
my_excel_converted = from_excel_to_list("""Paste here with ctrl-v the text""")
```

**Example**

Data from ctrl-c:

```
N   U   tot
1   18,236  18,236
17  20,37   346,29
5   6,318   31,59
```

Call The function:

```
from_excel_to_list("""N U   tot
1   18,236  18,236
17  20,37   346,29
5   6,318   31,59
""")
```

Result in Jupiter:

```
[['N', 'U', 'tot'],
 ['1', '18,236', '18,236'],
 ['17', '20,37', '346,29'],
 ['5', '6,318', '31,59']]
```

This is a base for further elaboration.
The same approach can be used to obtain dictionary, namedtuple and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For a small table, you can print the dataframe, use mouse to select the table, copy the table using Ctrl/Cmd + C, go to spreadsheet and paste the table, and you will get the following:
[image]

click on the first cell and insert a cell to fix the header:
[image]

Done.

PS: for a bigger table, some rows/columns will show as '...', refer to [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe) to show all rows and columns. For a even bigger table (that is difficult to select using the mouse), this method is not so convenient.