# Pandas outputting weirdly formatted dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I run this it outputs a weird dataframe, saying columns are missing etc... Even though I can see the columns in the html file.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as lh

with open("htmltabletest.html", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

    dfs = pd.read_html(soup.prettify())
    for df in dfs:
        print(df)
```

This outputs this:

```
   Unnamed: 0           ...                      Price  range
0         NaN           ...            $134.50  to  $2,222.50
1         NaN           ...             $20.39  to  $3,602.50

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

When I have this as `htmltabletest.html`:

```
<table class="dataTable st-alternateRows" id="eventSearchTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="th-es-rb"><div class="dt-th"> </div></th>
<th id="th-es-ed"><div class="dt-th"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Event date<br/>Time (local)</div></th>
<th id="th-es-en"><div class="dt-th"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Event name<br/>Venue</div></th>
<th id="th-es-ti"><div class="dt-th"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Tickets<br/>listed</div></th>
<th id="th-es-pr"><div class="dt-th es-lastCell"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Price<br/>range</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="" id="eventSearchTbody"><tr class="even" id="r-se-103577924">
<td class="nowrap"><input class="es-selectedEvent" id="se-103577924-check" name="selectEvent" type="radio"/></td>
<td class="nowrap" id="se-103577924-eventDateTime">Thu, 10/11/2018<br/>8:20 p.m.</td>
<td><div><a class="ellip" href="services/priceanalysis?eventId=103577924&amp;sectionId=0" id="se-103577924-eventName" target="_blank">Philadelphia Eagles at New York Giants</a></div><div id="se-103577924-venue">MetLife Stadium, East Rutherford, NJ</div></td>
<td id="se-103577924-nrTickets">6655</td>
<td class="es-lastCell nowrap" id="se-103577924-priceRange"><span id="se-103577924-minPrice">$134.50</span>  to<br/><span id="se-103577924-maxPrice">$2,222.50</span></td>
</tr><tr class="odd" id="r-se-103577925">
<td class="nowrap"><input class="es-selectedEvent" id="se-103577925-check" name="selectEvent" type="radio"/></td>
<td class="nowrap" id="se-103577925-eventDateTime">Thu, 10/11/2018<br/>8:21 p.m.</td>
<td><div><a class="ellip" href="services/priceanalysis?eventId=103577925&amp;sectionId=0" id="se-103577925-eventName" target="_blank">PARKING PASSES ONLY Philadelphia Eagles at New York Giants</a></div><div id="se-103577925-venue">MetLife Stadium Parking Lots, East Rutherford, NJ</div></td>
<td id="se-103577925-nrTickets">929</td>
<td class="es-lastCell nowrap" id="se-103577925-priceRange"><span id="se-103577925-minPrice">$20.39</span>  to<br/><span id="se-103577925-maxPrice">$3,602.50</span></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and the print is fine. But you should also try `display(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
<th id="th-es-rb"><div class="dt-th"> </div></th>
<th id="th-es-ed"><div class="dt-th"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Event date<br/>Time (local)</div></th>
<th id="th-es-en"><div class="dt-th"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Event name<br/>Venue</div></th>
<th id="th-es-ti"><div class="dt-th"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Tickets<br/>listed</div></th>
<th id="th-es-pr"><div class="dt-th es-lastCell"><span class="th-divider"> </span>Price<br/>range</div></th>
</tr>
```

Yours program works fine. Please notice that in line:

`<th id="th-es-rb"><div class="dt-th"> </div></th>`

you haven't any values. If you change yours input for ex.

```
<th id="th-es-rb"><div class="dt-th"> My new column </div></th>
```

It would work fine.

MY OUTPUT:

```
In [146]: df.columns

Out[146]: 
Index(['My new cole', 'Event date  Time (local)', 'Event name  Venue',
       'Tickets  listed', 'Price  range'],
      dtype='object')
```

In [145]: df

```
Out[145]: 
   My new cole    Event date  Time (local)  \
0          NaN  Thu, 10/11/2018  8:20 p.m.   
1          NaN  Thu, 10/11/2018  8:21 p.m.   
                                   Event name  Venue  Tickets  listed  \
0  Philadelphia Eagles at New York Giants  MetLif...             6655   
1  PARKING PASSES ONLY Philadelphia Eagles at New...              929   
             Price  range  
0  $134.50  to  $2,222.50  
1   $20.39  to  $3,602.50
```

Comment: Then why is my output not including the rest of the columns & data? There should be 3 more columns, for example `Event name`, along with the event name in the first row? It shouldnt be printing NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was that I am using IDLE instead of pycharm or something else to run the program. By default pandas doesn't print wide enough to fit my data. This has already been answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns)