# How to view all of DataFrame columns and the data, without middle points?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

My DataFrame looks like this (11 columns in total):

```
               Alpha      Beta     Gamma    ...        Sigma       Tau     Omega
2012-01-01  4.656792  9.419713  3.193772    ...     2.214034  2.553029  8.159858
2012-01-02  3.340358  9.038128  1.493114    ...     6.902116  8.070853  8.682406
2012-01-03  1.922536  6.609628  9.327669    ...     6.902920  6.510281  5.310958
2012-01-04  8.162849  7.631287  2.286857    ...     7.323811  1.580484  9.832999
2012-01-05  6.510500  9.488752  4.930104    ...     8.099461  3.252794  4.335705
```

I want to see all columns, without the middle points (dots).

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#pd.options.display.max_columns = 250
#pd.set_option('display.width',280) # default is 80
#pd.set_option('precision',7) # Digits after the dot.

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,11)*9+1,
               index=pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=5),
               columns=['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Epsilon','Theta','Lambda','Rho','Sigma','Tau','Omega'])
print (df.head())
```

I tried the following lines each time, but still i did not see all columns together...I am using python27.

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = 250

pd.set_option('display.width',280) # default is 80

pd.set_option('precision',7) # Digits after the dot.
```

Comment: @BallpointBen .  Perfect!...need to enable these lines:   pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

Comment: take a look at this answer first https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375383