# how to display full data in WinPython?

Tags: python

I have been using WinPython as a Python IDE and in the IPtyhon console found that everytime I want to display some data, it cuts it off. For example, instead of displaying something like:

```
1.000000        -0.055308    -0.034901 -0.034901 -0.034901   -0.034901 -0.080226
```

it cuts the information and displays something like:

```
1.000000        -0.055308    ...    -0.034901 -0.080226
```

How can I make to display the full data? I am just using the simple `print` instruction.

For example, my code is:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,9),index=dates,columns=list('ABCDEFGHI'))
    print df.corr()
```

and the data displayed is:

```
          A         B         C    ...            G         H         I
A  1.000000  0.275910  0.147713    ...     0.334278 -0.583099 -0.158927
B  0.275910  1.000000  0.415321    ...    -0.018651 -0.427883  0.844534
C  0.147713  0.415321  1.000000    ...    -0.074803 -0.741490  0.226847
D  0.126286  0.208167  0.953438    ...    -0.256444 -0.656777 -0.025928
E  0.822642  0.483059 -0.194566    ...     0.108853 -0.290930  0.107252
F -0.768350 -0.366595 -0.247973    ...    -0.008768  0.789135  0.119400
G  0.334278 -0.018651 -0.074803    ...     1.000000 -0.167573  0.135330
H -0.583099 -0.427883 -0.741490    ...    -0.167573  1.000000 -0.057962
I -0.158927  0.844534  0.226847    ...     0.135330 -0.057962  1.000000
```

I would like to see the data displayed fully, but it gets substituted by ..., how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your full code

Comment: a piece of code would be helpful.

Comment: this  may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns