# When using Pandas read_csv function, several cells trail off with "..." instead of having the full text. Any suggestions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, io

I saved an excel file into a CSV and uploaded it using Google Colab's `file.upload()`.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

If I view "uploaded" it shows the full file. When I save it into a data frame using:

```
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded["OilEx No Tickers.csv"].decode("utf-8")))
```

`data` returns

[image: websites cut off]

which is useless as the websites are cut off. They do not work in the function I am trying to run them through later as they aren't the full site. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `data.head()['Website']`?

Comment: Same problem happens with read_excel, but see Leimbigler's answer for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time I faced this problem myself, I bookmarked PX0r's answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns), which is to run this command, then re-display the DataFrame:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)
```

To reset this option to its default value without having to restart the kernel:

```
pd.reset_option('max_colwidth')
```

Some other useful commonly used options in the official docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that this was a setting with pandas itself, as I beveled it was with the the read_csv function. You have helped solve my issue. On to the next error!

Comment: @djdono, if this answer has solved your problem, then you should accept it. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/tour