# pandas in python showing full content of a data frame

Tags: python, neo4j

I would like to display the output of a query in Neo4j using the pandas data frame and write the result in a text file.

I can display the query but the output is always containing dots.

```
from py2neo import Graph
import pandas as pd
graph = Graph(host="63.35.194.218", auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
bidirectional_different_SAB = graph.run('MATCH (n1)-[r1:HAS_CHILD|HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n2)-[r2:HAS_CHILD|HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n1) WHERE r1.weight = r2.weight and id(n1) > id(n2) and r1.SAB<>r2.SAB RETURN  n1.prefered_name,r1.SAB, n2.prefered_name,r2.SAB, n1.id, n2.id;')
bidirectional_different_SAB = str(bidirectional_different_SAB.to_data_frame())
f= open("analysiss.txt","w+")
f.write("Display bidirectional relationships having different SAB")
f.write(bidirectional_different_SAB)
f.write("\n")
```

I would like to have all the data displayed in the text file with no dots
[image: This is the result shown, I need the result without dots]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the pandas data frame API to write the file directly.

```
df = bidirectional_different_SAB.to_data_frame()
df.to_csv("Display bidirectional relationships having different SAB.csv")
```

If you want the `repr` format, you can modify pandas options using `set_option` before you run the rest of your code.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width', 30000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)
```

As a third alternative, you can convert the data frame to string, pad it to fixed width per column, and then save the date frame to file using the pandas API.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_colwidth(col):
    w_header = len(col.name) if col.name else 0
    w_col = col.astype(str).str.len().max()
    return max(w_header, w_col)

def to_fixed_width(df):
    df_out = df.astype(str)
    for c in df_out:
        col = df_out[c]
        width = get_width(col)
        df_out[c] = col
    # convert the index to str as well
    ix = df_out.index
    df_out = df_out.set_index(ix.str.rjust(get_width(ix)))
    return df_out

df = bidirectional_different_SAB.to_data_frame()
df2 = to_fixedwidth(df)
# this uses the CSV writer to write the fixed width text file with a space as the separator
df2.to_csv("Display bidirectional relationships having different SAB.txt", sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use display options to define how your df should be printed:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

see this post for some examples:
[How do I expand the output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns)