# How to export a pandas dataframe to a latex table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

for my thesis, I need a large dataframe as a LaTeX table.
It contains 126 rows and 5 columns.
I know, that there is a function `df.to_latex(buf='citations.tex', largetable=True)`. However, when i run the function, it cuts of my strings in the columns!
I am using jupyter notebook. So when i print my dataframe there, the strings in the columns get abbreviated. This is all right. But when I use the `to_latex()` function on my dataframe, the columns get abbreviated as well. Why is this happening?

My Dataframe:

```
title                                              authors                            journal                                     year  doi
A visualization and modeling tool for security...  Reijo M. Savola; Petri Heinonen    2011 Information Security for South Africa  2011  10.1109/ISSA.2011.6027518
Information security requirements – Interpreti...  Mariana Gerber; Rossouw von Solms  Computers & Security                        2008  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cose.2008.07.009
```

After using `df.head(2).to_latex()`
The LaTeX output:

```
'\\begin{tabular}{llllrl}\n\\toprule\n{} &                                              title &                            authors &                                     journal &  year &                                         doi \\\\\n\\midrule\n0 &  A visualization and modeling tool for security... &    Reijo M. Savola; Petri Heinonen &  2011 Information Security for South Africa &  2011 &                   10.1109/ISSA.2011.6027518 \\\\\n1 &  Information security requirements – Interpreti... &  Mariana Gerber; Rossouw von Solms &                        Computers \\& Security &  2008 &  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cose.2008.07.009 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

As you can see, the textoutput is not an output of the dataframe, but rather from the printed version. Even exporting to a file, doesn't help. `df.to_latex('citations.tex', longtable=True)` is the command used, but it doesn't work as expected.

**Why is this happening, and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

I hope you managed to solve this by now, but just in case...

I had the same problem and stumbled upon your post here. As the previous solution only seems to apply for printing dataframes in the console, but not in the `to_latex` function, it didn't work for me.

I found this issue here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6491 and could solve the problem for me using

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1000)
```

or the solution proposed there:

```
with pd.option_context("max_colwidth", 1000):
  print df.to_latex()
```

Comment: Its a long time ago. When I have the time, I'll try to recreate your solution and see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a difference on your output if you set this:

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
 pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
 pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Comment: Nope, it stays the same. Columns get still abreviated, no matter if I use `df.head()`, `df.head().to_latex` or `df`

Comment: you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns)