# JSON Response into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I'm trying to get an API response from https://www.loves.com/api/sitecore/StoreSearch/SearchStores into a Pandas Dataframe. Specifically, I'm trying to load the 'Points' array into the data frame. I've seen other posts indicate that I should perhaps use json_normalize, and I've played around with that for a day but haven't made any progress.

```py
import json
import requests

def get(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    parsed = json.loads(response.text)
    return json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(get(lovesLocator), 'Points')
```

The error I keep receiving is:

```py
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
points = json.loads(requests.get("https://www.loves.com/api/sitecore/StoreSearch/SearchStores").text)[0]["Points"]
df = pd.DataFrame(points)
print(df.shape) # (580, 21)
```

Comment: Well that's excellent. A quick question though. I'm not getting all of the keys when I print the data frame. I only see: 'Address1 Address2  AddressId  AddressTypeId  \'. How can I get all of the keys to print in the df?

Comment: This is just a display issue. Pandas naturally limits the number of columns to be shown when printing a DataFrame. You can increase this limit:

    pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 500)
    pd.set_option("display.width", 1000)



For more info, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)