# How to find which columns have NAN values? (70+ columns)

Tags: python, pandas

Question as above. I always use this line of code `df.isna().sum()` to count the number of NAN values in each columns. This works great for dataset with 10-15 columns but when I have 20,30+ columns some of the output don't show, which gives me a hard time to find which col has NAN values. Is there a way to list out every column and its number of NANs?

the output of this line of code:

`Id               0
MSSubClass       0
MSZoning         0
LotFrontage      0
LotArea          0
                ..
MoSold           0
YrSold           0
SaleType         0
SaleCondition    0
SalePrice        0
Length: 77, dtype: int64`

some of the column names are replaced with `..`, I would like to see every column.

Comment: Yes thank you so much, i searched around but didn't find this.

Comment: please post the code for your data frame or the file here posting the image won't help         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I think my question was very straight forward. I have solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this will do the work...

```
df.isna().any()
```

Comment: it's the same problem. the output doesn't show every column I got

Comment: can you post your data frame here?

Comment: I have updated a screen shot in the question.

Comment: Just building on top of this answer. In case someone is looking on how to extract the columns with nans... `df.columns[df.isna().any()]` will probably help, and will work for any number of columns.