# Display full Pandas dataframe in Jupyter without index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to pretty-print in full (it's ~90 rows) in a Jupyter notebook. I'd also like to display it without the index column, if possible. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe). It covers rows and columns

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney - it helps for showing the full dataframe, but what about _not_ displaying the index column?

Comment: I do not think removing the index is an option unless you're printing to the clipboard like `df.to_clipboard(sep='\\s+', index=False)`

Answer (score 5):

For pretty-printing without an index, I think the right approach is to call the display method for HTML (which is what jupyter does under the hood):

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(df.to_html(index=False))
```

(Credit to [Display pandas dataframe without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64846520/display-pandas-dataframe-without-index))

As others have suggested you can use `pd.display_max_rows()` for the row count limitation.

Answer (score 4):

In pandas you can use this

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
```

please use this.

Without index use additionally.

```
df.to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: What about displaying it without the index column?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to omit the index, I convert to a styled data frame.

```
styled_df = df.style.format()
styled_df.hide()
```

.hide() gets rid of the index. You can also pass format mapping to the to get a nicer pretty print. Assuming you're formatting columns titled 'cashflow' and 'excess', that could look something like

```
format_mapping = {
    'cashflow': lambda x: f'{x:,.0f}',
    'excess': lambda x: f'{x:,.3f}'
}
styled_df = df.style.format(format_mapping)
styled_df.hide()
```

You can even do conditional formatting and other fun things with this approach.