# How to use the whole terminal in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do you get VSC to use the whole terminal when displaying output? I've got a problem with displaying tables, but sections keep getting cut out to fit only half of the terminal.

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711637/5285732) (no, I haven't downvoted your question)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `"console": "externalTerminal",` in the setting file "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)", and then click `F5` to debug the code. The result will be displayed in a separate terminal:

[image]

Reference: [Console in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).