# VS code // It doesn t show me all the rows of data on my terminal

Tags: python, database, visual-studio-code, terminal, rows

I run this python code on VS code to get historical data of some stocks i choose.

**The python code**

```
from pandas_datareader import data
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime

STAR_DATE = '2005-01-01'
END_DATE = str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

UK_STOCK = 'UU.L'
USA_STOCK = 'AMZN'

def get_data(ticker):
    try:
        stock_data = data.DataReader(ticker,
                                    'yahoo',
                                     STAR_DATE,
                                    END_DATE)
        print(stock_data)    
                            
    except RemoteDataError:
        print('No Data found for {t}'.format(t=ticker))

get_data(USA_STOCK)
```

[image: Code]

I run the code and everything is going fine. But it doesn t show in the termninal all the rows of data i want. It shows me only a part of that rows.
**It says 4071 rows, yet it doesn t show all of that rows.**

[image]

**How do i display in the terminal all the rows?**

Comment: This link might help you with your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thank you so much!! I found it!

Comment: I found the answer in that link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe