# pd.info() with 184 columns

Tags: python, pandas, info

I have a DataFrame with 184 columns and i want to print the df.info() result with the NA count.
In the same logic of the print of DataFrame in the question here:

[How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

But, when i try to do it with this code:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 184)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 300)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

df.info()
```

I dont have the result expected:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1690516 entries, 0 to 1690515
Columns: 184 entries, code to carnitine_100g
dtypes: float64(123), int64(2), object(59)
memory usage: 2.3+ GB
```

someone know how to fix it?

Thanks

In the same logic, you can extand the print of DataFrame.
Look at the question here:

[How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: *"pd.info() with 184 columns"* is not a question. *"How do I get `pd.info()` to display all columns of a dataframe"* is a question. You could even search on the latter to find existing answers. You'd find the [9-year-old answer with 1085 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711637/202229), admittedly old, but points you in the right direction.

Comment: @smci that is **not** a dupe. The question you linked to refers to printing the df itself using `print(df)`

Comment: @DeepSpace: I'm aware of that, but answers there do also reference `max_info_columns` and you're free to point out the distinction. Since there's an interplay between whether you do/don't use jupyter, `max_width`, `max_columns`, `max_colwidth` and other options, also pandas changes frequently, also the introduction of context-handlers like `with option_context('display.max_rows', 10, 'display.max_columns', 5):`, it would be totally unreasonable to have a question for each variant; look how fast the answers age. So broadly yes it is a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html):

> max_cols, int, optional
> When to switch from the verbose to the truncated
> output. If the DataFrame has more than max_cols columns, the truncated
> output is used. **By default, the setting in**
> **pandas.options.display.max_info_columns is used**.

So you need to set

```
pd.set_option('display.max_info_columns', 128)
```

Or, since it does not support `None`, in a more dynamic way (obviously will only work after `df` is created):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_info_columns', len(df.columns))
```

Comment: Thanks! this what i needed

Comment: Please post this at the existing question [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe) and people can upvote your answer there. This reasking is likely to be closed-as-dupe.

Comment: @smci that is **not** a dupe. The question you linked to refers to printing the df itself using `print(df)`

Comment: @DeepSpace: I'm aware of that, but answers there do also reference `max_info_columns` and you're free to point out the distinction. Since there's an interplay between whether you do/don't use jupyter, `max_width`, `max_columns`, `max_colwidth` and other options, also pandas changes frequently, also the introduction of context-handlers like `with option_context('display.max_rows', 10, 'display.max_columns', 5):`, it would be totally unreasonable to have a question for each variant; look how fast the answers age. So broadly yes it is a dupe.