# Python pandas concat dont show columns when more then three

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Hi I just wrote a little program for a bingo game, where I can randomize names and sentences(phrases).
I prepare them in two csv sheets and bring them together via pandas concat into one txt sheet.
But when I try to create a sheet with more then three columns, I always get the following:
[columns disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OIvi.png)

Why are the column 1 and 2 not there?

Here is the complete code:
[complete code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIQKD.png)

Comment: Coloumns 1 and 2 are there. They're just not displayed to save space.
You can look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem.