# Pandas: Can't display() the entire df despite setting all options to max (None)?

Tags: python

I'm using `pandas 1.2.4` and `python 3.9.1`.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe) I have reset the display options as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
```

I also tried adding

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
```

without success.

The output is however still truncated starting from column 5 (49 characters:)

```
821285;chr17:57851246:+;chr17:57721637:+;ENSG0...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The accepted answer says that most of that stuff is deprecated. Try the one from @arispen.

Comment: Still not sure how the admins handle things here. If the answer with the most upvotes is deprecated, why is it not removed and replaced with @arispens?

Comment: There are questions here that are +12 years old and one has to scroll down to look for updated answers if the author of the accepted one hasn't put any updates (which most do actually, which are the ones with a crazy amount of rep). I don't think anyone is doing anything about that, but I don't think deleting an answer altogether is a good solution. If you want to further discuss this, you can go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and ask people directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Camilo Martínez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13223456/camilo-mart%c3%adnez) in the comment I tried @arispens version with a slight modification (using `None` instead of `-1`). I left the code above unchanged just adding a single line:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)
```

This did the trick for me in `python 3.9.1` with `pandas 1.2.4`.