# yfinance print max rows python

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
import yfinance as yf

data = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='5d', interval='5m')

print(data)
```

This returns a large text-based table, with `[330 rows x 6 columns]` at the bottom. Some of the rows are replaced with `...`, and only 10 rows are printed. How do I change this and make it print every single row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas` then `pd.set_options()`.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
data = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='5d', interval='5m')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: @Hugh67945 has this helped or no?