# Expand value_counts() view?

Tags: python, pandas, count, distinct-values, visualize

Does anybody know how I visualize all values?

[image]

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [pandas set_option docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html), `display.max_rows` is the value you need to modify. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

To display unlimited rows.