# How to print dataframe result?

Tags: python, dataframe, yfinance

I saw a code on reddit and I am trying to figure out how the author got the end result. I tried display(df), but could only get VWAP to show, but not the upper and lower vwap.

I just wanted to clarify, the issue is that the upper and lower vwap are not extracted at all. I don't think it's because the code is not showing the full thing.

I have also tried print(key), print(day_data), print(df.loc) etc.

```
                                Open        High         Low       Close  \
Datetime                                                                    
2021-10-21 09:30:00-04:00  856.000000  861.515015  855.504578  859.280029   
2021-10-21 09:31:00-04:00  859.568970  862.219910  857.000000  861.499878   
2021-10-21 09:32:00-04:00  861.240295  863.729980  859.500000  863.090027   
2021-10-21 09:33:00-04:00  863.489990  865.330017  862.000000  862.929993   
2021-10-21 09:34:00-04:00  868.000000  869.199890  868.000000  869.199890   
...                               ...         ...         ...         ...   
2021-10-21 15:55:00-04:00  894.380005  894.750000  894.260071  894.489990   
2021-10-21 15:56:00-04:00  894.510010  894.559998  894.200073  894.369995   
2021-10-21 15:57:00-04:00  894.299988  894.469971  894.075989  894.210022   
2021-10-21 15:58:00-04:00  894.197021  894.469971  894.000000  894.140015   
2021-10-21 15:59:00-04:00  894.140015  894.150024  893.500000  893.599976   

                           Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits        vwap  
Datetime                                                                
2021-10-21 09:30:00-04:00  908134          0             0  858.766541  
2021-10-21 09:31:00-04:00  247621          0             0  859.082215  
2021-10-21 09:32:00-04:00  192159          0             0  859.513382  
2021-10-21 09:33:00-04:00  241155          0             0  860.106245  
2021-10-21 09:34:00-04:00  256713          0             0  861.315370  
...                           ...        ...           ...         ...  
2021-10-21 15:55:00-04:00   94604          0             0  888.946133  
2021-10-21 15:56:00-04:00   74274          0             0  888.959541  
2021-10-21 15:57:00-04:00  132418          0             0  888.982735  
2021-10-21 15:58:00-04:00  145736          0             0  889.007794  
2021-10-21 15:59:00-04:00  189346          0             0  889.037185
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/algotrading/comments/gman9v/calculating_vwap_bands/

Thank you.

```
 def caclulate_vwap_bands(self, df, curr_date, num_days):
        key = 'VWAP'
        def stdev(df):
            return df[key].values.std(ddof=0)
        curr_position = datetime.datetime.combine(curr_date, time(hour=9, minute=31))
        df.loc[str(curr_position), 'UPPER_VWAP'] = None
        df.loc[str(curr_position), 'LOWER_VWAP'] = None
        df.loc[str(curr_position), 'STD_VWAP'] = None
        for _ in range(0, num_days):
            day_data = df[curr_date == df.index.date].copy()
            for _ in range(31, 60):
                try:
                    std = stdev(day_data[day_data.index.time <= curr_position.time()])
                    df.loc[str(curr_position), 'UPPER_VWAP'] = df.loc[str(curr_position), key] + (2 * std)
                    df.loc[str(curr_position), 'LOWER_VWAP'] = df.loc[str(curr_position), key] - (2 * std)
                    df.loc[str(curr_position), 'STD_VWAP'] = std
                except:
                    print(curr_position, "doesn't exist, skipping")
                curr_position += timedelta(minutes=1)
            for _ in range(10, 17):
                while True:
                    if curr_position.time() >= time(hour=16, minute=1):
                        break
                    std = stdev(day_data[day_data.index.time <= curr_position.time()])
                    try:
                        df.loc[str(curr_position), 'UPPER_VWAP'] = df.loc[str(curr_position), key] + (2 * std)
                        df.loc[str(curr_position), 'LOWER_VWAP'] = df.loc[str(curr_position), key] - (2 * std)
                        df.loc[str(curr_position), 'STD_VWAP'] = std
                    except:
                        print(curr_position, "doesn't exist, skipping")
                    curr_position += timedelta(minutes=1)
            curr_position += timedelta(days=1)
            curr_position = curr_position.replace(hour=9, minute=31)
```

End result should be this

```
                        VWAP  UPPER_VWAP  LOWER_VWAP  STD_VWAP
date                                                                    
2020-05-15 09:31:00  282.4667  282.466700  282.466700  0.000000
2020-05-15 09:32:00  282.4727  282.483300  282.462100  0.005300
2020-05-15 09:33:00  282.5034  282.514517  282.492283  0.005558
2020-05-15 09:34:00  282.5159  282.526233  282.505567  0.005166
2020-05-15 09:35:00  282.4693  282.479148  282.459452  0.004924
...                       ...         ...         ...       ...
2020-05-15 15:56:00  284.1254  285.181526  283.069274  0.528063
2020-05-15 15:57:00  284.1421  285.201229  283.082971  0.529565
2020-05-15 15:58:00  284.1532  285.215345  283.091055  0.531072
2020-05-15 15:59:00  284.1712  285.236408  283.105992  0.532604
2020-05-15 16:00:00  284.2078  285.276242  283.139358  0.534221
```

Comment: did you try just `print(df)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: print(df) result is similar to display(df) except that it's not in a table.
With regards to expanding columns, it didn't work. It seems like the upper and lower vwap wasn't extracted with print(df). Thank you!

Comment: Use `df.to_string()` to print the df without any shrinkage.