# How to remove ellipsis from a row in a Python Pandas series or data frame, shown when long lines/wide columns are truncated?

Tags: python, pandas, printing, column-width

When I create the following Pandas Series:

```
    pandas.Series(['a', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']
```

I get this as a result:

```
    0                                                    a
    1    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
    2    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
    3                                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    4    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

How can I instead get a Series without the ellipsis that looks like this:

```
    0                                                                         a
    1    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    2         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    3                                                          aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    4        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

pandas is truncating the output, you can change this:

```
In [4]:

data = pd.Series(['a', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'])

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',1000)

data

Out[4]:

0                                                                         a
1    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3                                                          aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
4        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
dtype: object
```

also see related: [Output data from all columns in a dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361985/output-data-from-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas?lq=1) and [Output data from all columns in a dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361985/output-data-from-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas?lq=1)

By the way if you are using IPython then if you do a docstring lookup (by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>) then you will see the current values and the default values (the default is 50 characters).

For Pandas versions older than 0.10 use

```
pd.set_printoptions(max_colwidth, 1000)
```

See related: [Python pandas, how to widen output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-widen-output-display)

Comment: For newer versions of `pandas`, you should directly use `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 1000`