# Print very long string completely in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am struggling with the seemingly very simple thing. I have a pandas data frame containing very long string.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : ['one', 'two', 
      'This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string']})
```

Now when I try to print the same, I do not see the full string I rather see only part of the string.

I tried following options

- using `print(df.iloc[2])`
- using `to_html`
- using `to_string`
- One of the Stack Overflow answers suggested to increase column width by using pandas display option, that did not work either.
- I also did not get how `set_printoptions` would solve this.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

You can use `options.display.max_colwidth` to specify you want to see more in the default representation:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                                                 one
0                                                one
1                                                two
2  This is very long string very long string very...

In [3]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth
Out[3]: 50

In [4]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                                                                               one
0                                                                              one
1                                                                              two
2  This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string
```

And indeed, if you just want to inspect the one value, by accessing it (as a scalar, not as a row as `df.iloc[2]` does) you also see the full string:

```
In [7]: df.iloc[2,0]    # or df.loc[2,'one']
Out[7]: 'This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string'
```

Comment: df.iloc[2,0]  -- doesnt work - I will print first and third row and cutted(

Comment: It does work, if you want element of third row and first column. If you want something else, please open a new question.

Comment: It works, thx! I have a list of zip codes in 1 column and use apply to find the min and max column wise using a function: df['zipcodeMinMax'] = df.loc[:,['zipcodeList']].apply(createMinMaxZipcode, axis=1).  So within the function I do to_string on the series (stringZipcodes = zipcodeList.to_string(header=False, index=False)). The longer lists of zipcodes resulted in 3 dots at the end e.g. "1111...". Indeed this does not happen if you select the values based on index and column (as a scalar). My question: why this behaviour? Setting display options to influence apply seems strange to me? Thx!

Comment: FYI I added this to make sure the colwidth is sufficient for the length of the strings in the series:

colwidth = 500
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',colwidth)
if df['zipcodeList'].str.len().max() > colwidth:
            raise ValueError ('The max width is less than the max length of the string of zipcodes')

Comment: @Wouter if you have a different question, better to ask a new one instead of commenting here

Comment: This does not work for a bigger string like a paragraph with multiple lines.

Comment: If you want a more useable format that breaks long strings (or str representations of lists, etc) into multiple lines [@omnesia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691689/623735) is your ticket to success.

Answer (score 114):

Use `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` for automatic linebreaks and multi-line cells.

[This](http://songhuiming.github.io/pages/2017/04/02/jupyter-and-pandas-display/) is a great resource on how to use jupyters display with pandas to the fullest.

---

Edited:
Used to be `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)`.

Comment: An update for pandas >= v1.0: use None instead of -1

Answer (score 28):

Another, pretty simple approach is to call  list function:

```
list(df['one'][2])
# output:
['This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string']
```

No worth to mention, that is not good to convent to list the whole columns, but for a simple line - why not

Comment: If you have been whittling down your df based on some search criteria, and it is down to a single line, this doesn't work.  It's the simplest way, for debugging needs anyway, and I wish it would work, but I don't know why it doesn't.  You get a "*** KeyError: 0".  I'm guessing it has to do with being like a "scalar" when there's only one value.

Comment: As of today, this returns all the characters with a query into the df that returns two cells with 127 characters, that I've been frustrated in trying to get at.  If that helps anyone

Comment: It can be like this too: `list(df['one'])[2]` - only get the string, not as a list!

Answer (score 21):

Another easier way to print the whole string is to call `values` on the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : ['one', 'two', 
      'This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string']})

print(df.values)
```

The Output will be

```
[['one']
 ['two']
 ['This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string']]
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add the following line to your code before print.

```
 pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 90  # set a value as your need
```

**You can simply do the following steps for setting other additional options,**

- You can change the options for pandas max_columns feature as follows to display more columns

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  pd.options.display.max_columns = 10
  ```

  (this allows 10 columns to display, you can change this as you need)
- Like that you can change the number of rows as you need to display as follows to display more rows

  ```
  pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
  ```

  (this allows to print 999 rows at a time)

this should works fine

Please kindly refer the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) to change more options/settings for pandas

Answer (score 7):

I have created a small utility function, this works well for me

```
def display_text_max_col_width(df, width):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', width):
        print(df)

display_text_max_col_width(train_df["Description"], 800)
```

I can change length of the width as per my requirement, without setting any option permanently.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using jupyter notebook, you can also print pandas dataframe as HTML table, which will print full strings.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

Output

```
    one
0   one
1   two
2   This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you meant to do ?

```
In [7]: x =  pd.DataFrame({'one' : ['one', 'two', 'This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string']})

In [8]: x
Out[8]: 
                                                 one
0                                                one
1                                                two
2  This is very long string very long string very...

In [9]: x['one'][2]
Out[9]: 'This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string'
```

Answer (score 4):

The way I often deal with the situation you describe is to use the `.to_csv()` method and write to stdout:

```
import sys

df.to_csv(sys.stdout)
```

Update: it should now be possible to just use `None` instead of `sys.stdout` with similar effect!

This should dump the whole dataframe, including the entirety of any strings. You can use the to_csv parameters to configure column separators, whether the index is printed, etc. It will be less pretty than rendering it properly though.

I posted this originally in answer to the somewhat-related question at [Output data from all columns in a dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361985/output-data-from-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)