# Pandas - Formatting dataframe rows not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, formatting

I am trying to format the rows of my data frame, without success.

My data frame output is:

```
                       X                              Y
443   cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a0b00a5dc4f9     889.825    
111   ae3faf7ed08967e93d5f5ed6e10a5b256ec8c7fa     883.275    
221   601f669c760687b84ec57fe1eec213e26114a262     868.345   
631   80f54ce2aa2839e80cd5447cb369ec31f5e1fd47     867.545
```

I would like the output in the following format:

```
{"X": "cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a0b00a5dc4f9", "Y": 889.8}
{"X": "ae3faf7ed08967e93d5f5ed6e10a5b256ec8c7fa", "Y": 883.2}
```

I tried with:

```
format = '{"X": "{}", "Y": {%.1f}}'.format
my_df.apply(lambda x: format(**x), 1)
```

and:

```
my_df.style.format({'X': '{"X": "{}",', 'Y': '"Y": {%.1f}}'})
```

and:

```
my_df.to_string(formatters={'X':'"X": "{}",'.format, 'Y':'"Y": {%.1f}'.format})
```

None worked for me. This last attempt (`to_string`) is returning the following error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1781, in get_result
>       fmt_values = self._format_strings()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1961, in _format_strings
>       return [self.formatter(x) for x in self.values]
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1961, in 
>       return [self.formatter(x) for x in self.values]
>   KeyError: '%'

Any suggestion/help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working last solution with change [`%` to `:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15263885/2901002):

```
df = df.to_string(formatters={'X':'"X": "{}",'.format, 'Y':'"Y": {:.1f}'.format})
print (df)
                                                    X          Y
443  "X": "cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a0b00a5dc4f9", "Y": 889.8
111  "X": "ae3faf7ed08967e93d5f5ed6e10a5b256ec8c7fa", "Y": 883.3
221  "X": "601f669c760687b84ec57fe1eec213e26114a262", "Y": 868.3
631  "X": "80f54ce2aa2839e80cd5447cb369ec31f5e1fd47", "Y": 867.5
```

If need new formatting column is possible use list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = ['"X": "{}", "Y": {:.1f}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(df['X'], df['Y'])]
print (df)
                                            X        Y  \
443  cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a0b00a5dc4f9  889.825   
111  ae3faf7ed08967e93d5f5ed6e10a5b256ec8c7fa  883.275   
221  601f669c760687b84ec57fe1eec213e26114a262  868.345   
631  80f54ce2aa2839e80cd5447cb369ec31f5e1fd47  867.545   

                                                   new  
443  "X": "cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a0b00a5dc4f9...  
111  "X": "ae3faf7ed08967e93d5f5ed6e10a5b256ec8c7fa...  
221  "X": "601f669c760687b84ec57fe1eec213e26114a262...  
631  "X": "80f54ce2aa2839e80cd5447cb369ec31f5e1fd47...
```

Comment: It worked. But the X values are being printed as "cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a...", which is incomplete. What can I do in order to output the complete string? "cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a0b00a5dc4f9" instead of "cd2a9dd781c1396d4000ae05fcc3a..."? Thank you.

Comment: @Dalton Cézane it is display problem and solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29902714/2901002)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
my_df.to_dict(orient='records')
```