# How to select all text from cell in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have very long text in excel cell, when I want to read this it only shows a few lines. How to get all text from a cell?

```py
text=self.alco.loc[self.alco['Name']=='Vodka']['description']

text=text.to_string(index=False)
```

Output:

Vodka is a distilled beverage composed primari...

Comment: Did you check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/) website?

Comment: This worked for me! - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691689/10666495

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print very long string completely in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902714/print-very-long-string-completely-in-pandas-dataframe)