# Displaying full content of DataFrame cell without ellipsis truncating the text

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to display the contents of an Excel file in a Jupyter Notebook. However,  a column named `definition` of the Excel sheet contains long strings. So when I display the DataFrame in the notebook, the long strings are truncated by ellipsis (`...`).

[image]

Is there a way to display the complete contents of the column in Jupyter Notebook? Since there is clearly space to the right that can utilized by the `Definition` column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `options.display.max_colwidth` to specify you want to see more in the default representation:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                                                 one
0                                                one
1                                                two
2  This is very long string very long string very...

In [3]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth
Out[3]: 50

In [4]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                                                                               one
0                                                                              one
1                                                                              two
2  This is very long string very long string very long string veryvery long string
```

reference - [Print very long string completely in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902714/print-very-long-string-completely-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Is `pandas.set_option` not working? Try `import pandas as pd; pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)`

Look into `pd.option_context` as well if temporarily you need this width!