# How to view the entire line of a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which one column is a description column, each cell in the column is a lengthy string. While I open the DF, I only the the first few words followed by .... How do i see the entire description of each cell in the column?

Comment: See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351968/how-can-i-display-full-non-truncated-dataframe-information-in-html-when-conver

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

or

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

for older versions.

Full `set_option` documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you from https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215915/omnesia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691689/14535047

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```