# How to view the whole table

Tags: python-3.x, quandl

I am trying to get a table(dataset) using quandl. The table has 5rows X 12Columns but it is only showing 4 columns in the output and rest columns are replaced by 3 dots.
I wrote the following piece of code using Python:

```
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

for the output please refer to this image.
[image: Click Here]

P.S.: I tried using different IDEs for this code but the output was same.

Comment: Please do not post textual output as an image.

Comment: @Mr.T: sure. But it will look the same posted as text, minus the colors and fonts. Which do not seem to be part of the problem.

Comment: I don't know quandl, but looking at the output - [isn't it simply this pandas question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237914/8881141)

Comment: @Mr.T thanks mate that worked for me. I did the following changes in my code and it worked for me:
`import pandas as pd`
`import quandl`
`df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')`
`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`
`print(df.head())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution The following code will work perfectly:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Where did you find this? Could you please add the source?