# I want to see full table, python

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run my code I want to be able to see all columns, so instead of this(what I tried):

```
                                                NAZOV  ... ZOBRAZENIA
0                         YAMAHA FZ8-NA BLACK EDITION  ...      103 x
1                                   Kawasaki z800 Abs  ...     1847 x
2                                   Honda CMX500AK ED  ...     5924 x
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) works, but it is shown underneath and I want it next to each other. Just like table.

I want to see also that another 3 columns. Please help.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`

Comment: or, even better, do this: `df.T`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458892/how-to-view-the-whole-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Worked with combination of this:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
```

Thanx.