# How to get output of a column of a DataFrame?

Tags: python

How to get output of a column of a DataFrame?
Suppose, I have a DataFrame **DF**
which has columns: *name, marks, phone* in it.

How to het one of the column in python?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361985/output-data-from-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks, I am just started learning python. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the output of any columns by:

For Name:

```
DF["name"]
```

or you can use:

```
DF.name
```

Like this, you can insert the name of any column in place of "name".

Answer (score -1):

you can select one column, e.g. `DF["name"]` or `DF.name` and multiple columns by passing a list, e.g. `DF[["name", "marks"]]`.

Be careful with the `DF.name` notation as it doesn't work when the column name has special characters, e.g. whitespaces.